# Get bracket value from string with leading custom variable

Tags: c#, regex

I want to get a string that is in brackets behind a custom variable. 

For example: 
I have this string: "This is a test (I want to get the brackets from this: $variable(HeyGuys))." 
 
and I only want to get the string in the brackets behind the $variable: "HeyGuys" 
 

I tried two diffent things but both have the same result:

```
//Input
this.GetBracketValue("I want to get the brackets from this: $variable(HeyGuys)).", "$variable");

//What the output should look like:
"HeyGuys"

//What it looks like with what I tried:
"HeyGuys)"

// Version with regex
public string GetBracketValue(string message, string variable)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex("\\" + variable + "\\(.*\\)");
    string variable = regex.Match(message).Value;
    regex = new Regex("\\(.*\\)");

    foreach(Match match in regex.Matches(variable))
    {
        string result = match.Value.Remove(0, 1);
        result = result.Remove(result.Length - 1);
        return result;
    }
    return "";
}

// Version without regex
public string GetBracketValue(string message, string variable)
{
    int index = message.IndexOf(variable) + 1;
    string substring = "";
    if (index > 0)
    {
        substring = message.Substring(index);
        index = substring.IndexOf("(");
        if (index > 0)
        {
            substring = substring.Substring(substring.IndexOf("("));
            substring = substring.Remove(0, 1);
        }

        index = substring.LastIndexOf(")");
        if (index > 0)
        {
            substring = substring.Remove(substring.LastIndexOf(")"));
        }
    }
    return substring;
}
```

Comment: What is `commandVariable` and what is `response` ? Why so much obfuscation. Regex isn't obfuscated - > `(?<=junk you're looking for behind \()[^\)]*(?=\))`

Comment: I did a typo there. Changed it now

Comment: Why the `foreach`, you're just returning after the first match ? I mean it doesn't matter but it's hard to tell if you intend to return the first string result or a string array of values.

Comment: Its up to you but there are many ways to do this including a capture collection. I'm just saying you're not clear on what's being accomplished. Too bad really, the more clear you are, the _better_ answer you'll get. Why settle for more ambiguity ? Based on what you picked, the hard part is up to you now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
\$\w+\((\w+)\)
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

[image]

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/EVxqtc/4)

**Sample Implementation in C#**

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"\$\w+\((\w+)\)";
        string input = @"I want to get the brackets from this: $variable(HeyGuys)).";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

You can find the sample run of the above implementation in [**here.**](https://onlinegdb.com/Hk903EMyP)

Answer (score 2):

Try following :

```
            string input = "This is a test (I want to get the brackets from this: $variable(HeyGuys)).";
            string pattern = @"\$variable\((?'variable'[^\)]+)";

            Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
            string variable = match.Groups["variable"].Value;
```